# How to pass param in FileUploader in template?

Tags: angularjs

I use library `angular-file-upload` in Angular JS.
How I can pass options from template to object `FileUploader` in controller?

For example:

```
var uploader = $scope.uploader = new FileUploader({
     url: '/upload',
     formData: data,
     alias: 'files',
     autoUpload: true
});
```

I need pass param `formData` in init object `FileUploader`.

This is init HTML code:

```
<input type="file" nv-file-select="" uploader="uploader" multiple  />
```

Comment: May be put object new FileUploader in Factory?